# Primefaces AccordionPanel - how to expand space between tabs?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, accordion

How could I expand the space between the tabs of a [Primefaces AccordionPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanel.jsf) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my Chrome web developer toolset,

[image]

you just have to change the `margin-top` of the `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header`.

E.g., to 20px:

```css
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997)

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I also had to override the display property: `display: block;` since that div that your screenshot highlights was set to `display: none;` (which resulted in no space between tabs). One problem though: when I close tabs after I opened them, the div returns to be `display: none;`, i.e. no space. Probably by the javascript. How can I keep that space displayed after I close a tab??

Comment: Hmm right, totally overlooked that. Better set the top margin on the accordion header. E.g. `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
margin-top: 10px; }`. Does that what you want?

Comment: Close to perfect. It's what I want, except for the uppermost tab, for it I don't want that `margin-top` space... what I tried to do: defined css style: `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .do-nothing { margin-top: 0; }`, and on the first `p:tab` of `p:accordionPanel` I defined `styleClass="do-nothing"` - however I still get the space above the first accordion tab.. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should use `titleStyleClass` attribute and `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header.do-nothing` selector respectively.

Comment: I changed the attribute of `p:tab` (of `p:accordionPanel`) to `titleStyleClass="do-nothing"` but it changed nothing. Firebug still shows that this tab has `margin-top: 10px;`. Is there some bug? Using latest stable primefaces.

Comment: Apparently you haven't fixed the selector. Note that the `.do-nothing` should be set on the element matching `.ui-accordion.header` and not as a child of it. See my previous comment for the proper selector (just remove the space).

Comment: That made the difference! I wasn't aware of the difference that the space in the CSS selector can make. Thanks a lot! You solved the problem and also taught me something new about CSS.

Comment: You're welcome. A space in CSS selector indicates a child. See also http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching You could by the way also have used the `:first-child` pseudoselector without the need for a new class, but that doesn't work in IE6/7 (which shouldn't be a problem if you don't support those browsers anyway).

Comment: Thanks! Also for the `:first-child` tip.